# taxJar ratesForLocation not working

Tags: java, android-studio

In Android Studio setting a RateResponse variable (*In this case resp*) is causing the app to crash when the method is called

```
import com.taxjar.Taxjar;
import com.taxjar.exception.TaxjarException;
import com.taxjar.model.rates.RateResponse;`

public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity
{
Taxjar client = new Taxjar("APITOKEN"); //Real apiToken not shown
RateResponse resp;
public void findTax() {
    try{
        resp = client.ratesForLocation("90087");
    }
    catch (TaxjarException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is most of the Exception

```
13285-13285/com.example.braxton.taxcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    at com.taxjar.Taxjar$1.intercept(Taxjar.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)
    at com.taxjar.Taxjar.ratesForLocation(Taxjar.java:108)
    at com.example.braxton.taxcalculator.Calculator.findTax(Calculator.java:172)
    at com.example.braxton.taxcalculator.Calculator$2.onClick(Calculator.java:100)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Sorry for messy formatting or any missing information

Any ideas or input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Sorry, I added what I believe is the Exception